# Where should I keep Jira credentials for an application that accesses Jira REST API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I use the Jira API, which requires authentication to access and which gives the report I want.

I have no idea on where should I need to put the Jira credentials for my application. Can I put them in the source code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to include a [mre] that shows the code you are using to call the API.

Comment: Don't put credentials in your code. They belong to the local configuration: a config file, environment variable etc.

Answer (score 0):

use [dot env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) npm package

Create one hidden file called .env and store your credentials  and access from here. make sure dont push this file in your git.

see dotenv documentation for more clarification.

For an example:

.env file:

```
PORT=3000
```

create another file called config.js

```
   import dotenv from 'dotenv';
   dotenv.config();
   const ENV = process.env;

   console.log(ENV.PORT)
```